# Outlook push notification for multiple users from Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is there a way I can get events notifications from Outlook via MS Graph for multiple users. Following article talks about for individual user:
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations)

Can it be done using something similar like Application Impersonation as in the case of EWS (Exchange Web Services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Subscriptions have to be created and renewed for each user/mail folder. You can request the support for global subscriptions (kind of what teams has for all chat messages) for messages on [uservoice](https://Microsoftgraph.uservoice.com).